# ¿Cómo mejorar el rendimiento de un SELECT COUNT?

Tags: mysql, sql, rendimiento

Tengo una tabla "Oraciones" que contiene casi 23 millones de filas, y está creciendo rápidamente. Los gráficos de la metabase basados en ella son muy lentos de visualizar. Como puedo manejar esto para que los gráficos se muestren más rápido ?

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT count(distinct `prayers`.`from_user_id`) AS `count`
FROM `prayers`
WHERE (`prayers`.`created_at` >= date(date_add(now(6), INTERVAL -30 day))
   AND `prayers`.`created_at` < date(now(6)))
```

```
SELECT count(distinct `prayers`.`from_user_id`) AS `count`
FROM `prayers`
WHERE (`prayers`.`created_at` >= date(date_add(now(6), INTERVAL -7 day))
   AND `prayers`.`created_at` < date(now(6)))
```

Comment: Si siempre usas "los últimos 7/30 días", puedes obviar el problema precalculando los valores... O los calculas una vez a medianoche para los últimos 7/30 días, o tienes una tabla paralela de "OracionesCreadasPorDia", y al final de cada día creas el registro correspondiente al día que acaba de terminar.

Comment: o agregas indices.. o agregas una vista materializada... siempre hay cosas que se pueden hacer.. pero todas dependen de tu base y lo que puedas o no hacer....